# How to treat / convert javascript variables as / to ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, getelementbyid

I have few divs on my websites with different ids. Like so;

```
<div id = 'write1' style="color:#0000FF">
<div id = 'write2' style="color:#0000FF">
<div id = 'write3' style="color:#0000FF">
<div id = 'write5' style="color:#0000FF">
....
....
....
<div id = 'write*' style="color:#0000FF">
```

and then I have few buttons in my website like this;

```
  <button id = 'write1click' type="button">Click Me!</button> 
  <button id = 'write2click' type="button">Click Me!</button> 
  <button id = 'write3click' type="button">Click Me!</button> 
  <button id = 'write4click' type="button">Click Me!</button> 
    ....
    ....
    ....
 <button id = 'write*click' type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

In my javascript what I am doing is getting a reference to the div tags and buttons like so;

```
var write1 = document.getElementById("div1");
....
....
.... 
var write1click = document.getElementById("write1click");
```

and then what I am doing is extra all numbers from my button ids like this;

```
var getnumber = write1click.id.replace(/\D/g, ''); // This returns 1
```

and then I am creating another varaible which value of;

```
var finalVariable = 'write' + getnumber; // This returns write1
```

Now what the variable `finalVariable` contains initially is a id for the first div tag 'write1'. However the the website doesn't now that.

What I want to do is check whether there is a variable with this name and if there is I want to do particular task with it.

So for example in pseudo code it might look something like;

```
IF finalVariable Is or Matches a id of element in the website THEN
Do something
```

I am not sure if this is possible, if so, any help is welcomed. If I my question was not clear please let me know and I will try explaning it better.

Also, please note if this could be achieved without then need of refernecing the div id like this `var write1 = document.getElementById("div1");` However, as I am fairly new to website I am open to suggestion but I would like to now how this could be done.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You can improve the logic of your HTML and JS code by using common classes and then relate the `div` to the clicked `button` by their index. It's not obvious what the purpose of your `finalVariable` is though?

Comment: Currently I am linking them like you have suggested, however, I want to know, say for example, there is a varaible that contains a value which is same as one of the ids of a element the is it possible to use that variable to carry out some task with the id that matches the variable.

Comment: In this case, the variable 'finalVariable' value is 'write1'. This value is a id name for one of the div tags, what I want to do is use this variable to find out if there is a element on the page that contains this id and if so, I want to carry out some task.

Comment: You can use `$('#' + finalVariable).length > 0`, however surely if the `finalVariable` has a value, then the element has to exist already, as something was clicked on to set it? This is what I mean by the logic can be improved a lot to make it simpler and also reduce the amount of code. Could you setup a working example in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: In this case, the 'finalVariable' value is the id of one of the div element, so what I would like to do is, use this variable to say for exmaple change the innerHTML of the div tag. For example, 'finalVariable.innerHTML = 'something';'

Comment: the variable of finalVariable is made of up extracting letters/words from the button id.

Comment: But you have lots of different buttons, when are you getting the number from each of them?

Comment: This was just an example, in my website I have variable for each button that gets number and allocate to its relevant variable.

Comment: Ok, but my point remains that that is a bad pattern to use as it very inflexible, becomes a nightmare to maintain and results in a lot of unnecessary code. If you can post a working example of what you have I'm sure it can be made a lot more simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, JS code will be exactly your pseudo-code:

```
if (document.getElementById(finalVariable)) {
    // do something, ex: document.getElementById(finalVariable).style.color = 'blue';
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
if ($('#' + finalVariable).length) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried accessing the variable from the window object

```
if(!typeof window[finalVariable] === undefined){
     //your variable exists
     if(window[finalVariable] != null){
         //do something
     }
}
```